# SQL Agent Job failing

Tags: sql, biztalk

I have a BizTalk Server that has been configured per the instructions for BizTalk disaster recovery using the BizTalk Log Shipping implementation.

On the backup SQL Server, call it SQL02, the "Get Backup History" job fails constantly with the following error:

> Executed as user: DOMAIN\User. SQL
>   Server Network Interfaces: Error
>   getting enabled protocols list from
>   registry [xFFFFFFFF]. [SQLSTATE 42000]
>   (Error 65535)  OLE DB provider
>   "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "SQL01"
>   returned message "Login timeout
>   expired". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error
>   7412)  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for
>   linked server "SQL01" returned message
>   "A network-related or
>   instance-specific error has occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is
>   correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. For more information see
>   SQL Server Books Online.". [SQLSTATE
>   01000] (Error 7412).  The step failed.

This job executes a local stored procedure, which basically executes another stored procedure on a linked server, called SQL01.

When i execute this stored procedure in a query window on SQL02:
`EXEC [SQL01].[BizTalkMgmtDb_Prod].[dbo].[sp_GetBackupHistory]`
it executes without any errors.

When the SQL agent job attempts to execute the same query it fails with the error above.

Why can i execute the procedure manually and the sql agent job cannot?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and solved it by making sure the job runs against a database to which the job owner has access.

Answer (score 0):

check the sql agent and sql instance users it should have the rights and the users should be common for every instance or must have all the required rights.

In query you connect through a user which has the rights but the sql agent user does not have it (as per my understanding).

check your sql server configuration manager for checking users for services of sql server.

Comment: I have the owner of the job as a domain account that is not mapped to sysadmin role. As such the job executes as that user (as per my understanding, albeit very limited)
This can be seen in the error message; "Executed as user: DOMAIN\User."
If I switch the owner to another account that account appears in the message.
Funny thing, is if i switch the owner to myself (the account i can run the manual query as) it still fails with the same error!